# get value from shared_prefs XML on boot in android

Tags: android, xml

let say i have a myPrefs.xml in shared_prefs folder and i would like to retrieve the value within `myPrefs.xml` on boot.

How could i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

basically register to listen to the boot intent, then read your prefs file. Keep in mind that if you do a lot of processing in your broadcast receiver then your process will crash.